# Azure Media Service live streaming syndication

Tags: iis, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services, smooth-streaming

I would like to use Azure Media Services as an ingestion-point for live streaming, and I need to syndicate (push or pull) that stream to IIS running on my own servers within a local data-center.

When I configure a Live Smooth Streaming publishing point on my own server to pull from the 'Preview URL' of a channel or from a 'Publish URL' of a streaming unit ("{media services account name}.origin.mediaservices.net/{locator ID}/{filename}.ism"), my publishing point transitions immediately into an error state reporting "The remote computer responded with an HTTP error," or "Error: 0X80072EE7."

Is there any configuration I can enable to pull from an Azure stream, or configure Azure to push to a specific remote server?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Media Services (AMS) doesn't support push/pull to other publishing points. You cannot connect an on-premises IIS Media server to AMS. You can only configure a proxy such as ARR to cache the fragments in your data center.
Thanks,
Cenk